# How can I visualize hierarchical data?

Tags: r, graph, visualization, hierarchical-data, ggplot2

I have some data like the following:

```
A A1 12
A A2 23
A A3 AA1 1
A A3 AA2 2
B B1 2
B B2 1
```

Is there a way to visualize this information in ggplot? I am looking for something like this:

```
   |--A1---12
   |--A2---23
A--|--A3--AA1--1
      |---AA2--2

B--|--B1---2
   |--B2---1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a loot at "diagram" package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722689/creating-tree-diagram-for-showing-case-count-using-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`Rgraphviz`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.8/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html), which can allow you to visualize graphs (including trees), using different schemes for your nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Are you set on using ggplot? Personally, I would not process this kind of data in R since it's not really of statistical nature. I would rather write a python script to build a tree/forest, and view it using one of the many excellent graph visualization tools out there, e.g. [**Gephi**](http://gephi.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the function `sizetree()` in the `plotrix` package.

also treemaps make allow nice visualizations, see package `treemap`

finally check out either the javascript library **protovis** or **d3js**, both have great possibilities for visualizing hierarchies. it is a bit tedious to get the data in there though...